# Based on the routing transition and animate only certain components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React web application with tabs like navigation and each tab has a separate route. With a certain route I can access the certain tab and vice versa clicking on certain tab gets me to that route.

The problem is I would like to make the routing from the tabs to transition and animate only certain components and not the whole view - only the ones that actually change depending on the route.

It's possible to, depending on the route, animate only certain components?

Answer (score 0):

You're routes should have a common parent, that will animate the transition using react css transition group:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}> // The parent
    <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
    <Route path="page1" component={Page1}/>
    <Route path="page1" component={Page2}/>
    <Route path="page1" component={Page3}/>
    <Route path="page1" component={Page4}/>
</Route>
```

In the routes container decide if the path should animate, and turn on/off transitionEnter and transitionLeave:

```
const App = ({ children, location }) => {
  const pathsToAnimate = ['/page1', '/page3']; // a list of routes that should animate
  const shouldAnimate = pathsToAnimate.includes(location.pathname); // check if the current route is among the pathsToAnimate
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        component="div"
        transitionName="example"
        transitionEnter={ shouldAnimate } // animate if shouldAnimate is true
        transitionLeave={ shouldAnimate } // animate if shouldAnimate is true
        transitionEnterTimeout={500}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
      >
        {React.cloneElement(children, {
          key: location.pathname
        })}
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>

    </div>
  );
};
```